# Formatting localized numbers with unit symbols

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

#### Situation

I want to format a Double `23.54435678` into a String like `23.54 fps` respecting the user's locale.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let formatted = formatter.string(from: fps as NSNumber)! + " fps"
```

For the localized number formatting I use `DateFormatter`.

#### Question

How should I handle the unit part? Is it valid to just append the unit to the formatted number? Is the placement of the symbol not locale dependent? How do I handle that?

Comment: "fps", that's for "frame per seconds" right? While the formatting might know some symbols/units, I don't think it knows the fps. I'd rather use a localizable string for it, letting the translation of where to put the "fps" and how to translate it (and other translation).

Comment: Yup, "fps" is for "frames per second". To clarify, you say using a `DateFormatter` for the number and then a localized string with format to insert the number into the string? I see, makes total sense.

Comment: If it was meters, time, money, the formatters in CocoaTouch manage it. Fps, that’s more a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa has no built-in support for the unit "frames per second", so you will have to provide the suffix yourself, e.g. using Xcode's localization system.

You still need to format the numeric value with `NumberFormatter` for the current locale and then insert the resulting number string into the localized format string:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let numberString = formatter.string(from: fps)
let formatString = NSLocalizedString("%@ fps", comment: "") // provide localizations via .strings files
let fpsString = String(format: formatString, arguments: numberString)
```

If unit placement is locale-dependent (you will have to this find out yourself for the target locales of your app), you have to deal with this manually as well. You can leverage the localization system here by providing localizations with an adequately positioned placeholder for the numeric value, e.g. `%@ fps` for English and `x %@ yz` for... well, Fantasy Language.

Comment: Makes total sense, I already started doing this in response to @Larme's comment. Thanks!